# How to find all columns which data type is a "user defined data type"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-types

The scenario is as follows. I have a database in which there's a couple of user defined data types, which may be used as data types of some columns(not sure). Is there a way to check which columns are using these data types, so I can alter them?
I already think I know a way this could be done by the usage of Java and JDBC, but if there's a query that can achieve the same goal, it will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If anybody else has this problem you can query `information_schema.columns` and target the `DOMAIN_NAME` which will be different than `null` if the column is used user defined data type.

Comment: Hello @DaleK, I didn't know I had to accept answers. I will revisit my questions and the answers given and do that, thanks for the tip. I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that `information_schema.columns` can be used to gather this information.
The column `DOMAIN_NAME`will have a value different than `null` if the columns data type is user defined.

The query I executed to gather all the columns with user defined data type is

```
SELECT table_name [Table Name], column_name [Column Name]
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE DOMAIN_SCHEMA = '<specify_schema>'
AND DOMAIN_NAME LIKE '<specify_data_type>'
```